# Activeadmin double label text in login form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

All of my sites using active admin have this issue

There is extra text in my login form.

Has anyone seen this before

[image: ActiveAdmin Double label text]

**Html output**

```
<ol>Email<li class="email input required autofocus stringish" id="admin_user_email_input"><label    class="label" for="admin_user_email">Email<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label><input  autofocus="autofocus" id="admin_user_email" maxlength="255" name="admin_user[email]" type="email" value="">

</li>Password<li class="password input required stringish" id="admin_user_password_input"><label class="label" for="admin_user_password">Password<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label><input id="admin_user_password" maxlength="128" name="admin_user[password]" type="password">

</li>Remember me<li class="boolean input optional" id="admin_user_remember_me_input"><input name="admin_user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0"><label class="" for="admin_user_remember_me"><input id="admin_user_remember_me" name="admin_user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1">Remember me</label>

</li></ol>
```

**admin/admin_user.rb**

```
  ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  filter :email
  filter :current_sign_in_at
  filter :sign_in_count
  filter :created_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you have in your admin_user.rb file?

Comment: admin_user file has now been added to the question.

Comment: I tried to do this on one of my active admin apps but couldn't replicate it. Was this under source control (i.e. git)?

Comment: Yes am using git, should I look trough the log for the destroy command and post the changes here.

Comment: Yup. A diff would definitely help. I suspect when you ran the install again it appended code somewhere but I wasn't able to replicate it locally.

Comment: The issue is unrelated to the destroy command I notice this issue now on all of my sites.

Comment: Any luck with this @sasdev?